# Value property on input element only updates once

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

When I enter any number larger than 1 into the input element -- input value changes to 1 (because of the validation). For some reason, this works only for the first number I enter. If I, for example, enter 11, input value changes to 11, but it should change to 1. At least that's how I remember it worked in Angular 1. Any idea what's happening?

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  template:`
  <input 
     type="number"
     (input)="validate($event.target.value)" 
     [value]="duration">
  <p>{{duration}}</p>`
})
export class OneComponent{
  duration: number;
  constructor(){
    this.duration = 0;
  }
  validate(value){
    if(value > 1) {
      this.duration = 1;
    }
    else {
      this.duration = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/0clelaU5UitDR3gEyJJX/) (one.component.ts)

Comment: what is your requirement? I couldn't understand your first line.

Comment: @micronyks, I want the number on the input element to change to 1 if the value I entered is larger than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is tricking change detection. With this workaround change detection recognizes all changes and updates your `[value]="duration"` binding.

```ts
export class OneComponent{
  duration: number;
  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){
    this.duration = 0;
  }
  validate(value){
    this.duration = -1;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    if(value > 1) {
      this.duration = 1;
    }
    else {
      this.duration = value;
    }
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pHongL4Px2nysaBd5qu6?p=preview)

Comment: yay, it works! I love you, good sir! Thank you for your time and knowledge!

Comment: You're welcom. The `detectChanges()` call at the end might not be necessary. After the event Angular should run change detection anyway.